# My AJAX search isn't working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been trying to set-up an AJAX live search by following [Railscast #240](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) with no luck. I believe I have everything coded and placed properly per the tutorial. And I have the jquery-rails gem installed and the server restarted. I've placed the `javascript_include_tag`'s in the `<head>`. however the search reacts exactly the way it did before. Is there something i'm missing?

application.html.erb

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffold", "elements", "layout" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery_ujs' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

application.js

```
$(function() {
  $("#tag_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#tag_search").attr("action"), $("#tag_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

_tag_list.html.erb

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= button_to "#{tag.name} - #{tag.reports.size}", assign_tag_url(:tag_id => tag.id, :report_id => @report.id), :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

show.js.erb

```
$("#tag_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("tag_list")) %>");
```

show.html.erb

```
<div id="search_tags">
    <%= form_tag @report, :method => :get, :id => "tag_search" do %>
        <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search_tags, params[:search_tags], :placeholder => 'search tags...' %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div id="tag_list">
    <%= render 'tag_list' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Try debugging it with Firebug (for Firefox) or Chrome Developer Tools (just press Shift+Ctrl+I).

Comment: it shows data sending and receiving when it should... so i'm thinking it may just not be updating the content for some reason.

Comment: i tried moving the `render 'tag_list'` call into the `#tag_search form.` no difference

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your 'application.js' after 'jquery.js'.

Comment: good thought, and probably good practice, so I made the change, but it didn't help